# Restarting Unity Server from a Client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, server

Completely new territory for me here. I have a LAN networked game that I'm wanting to create the functionality to restart my UNET server remotely from a connected client. Looking for some feedback on the method that I'm starting to work on. Is this the correct approach to be thinking towards? Thank you!

```
[Server]
public void RestartServer()
{
    StartCoroutine(DoRestartServer());
}

[Server]
IEnumerator DoRestartServer()
{
    Debug.Log("Network Server Shut Down");
    NetworkServer.Shutdown();

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Destroy(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("NetworkManager"));
    Debug.Log("Network Manager Shut Down");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10.0f);

    Instantiate(ForestGameManager.fgm.serverNetworkManagerPrefab);
    Debug.Log("Network Manager Started Up");

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm no expert (worked on a few server side apps), but I'd think that this is asking for trouble? One of the first things I learned to implement was "never trust a client". However, if you absolutely must, it looks OK overall